# Remove duplicate words from field in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if it is possible to remove duplicate text using a mysql query from one field, or if a problem like this would be better solved using PHP.

I have a database where users enter tags which can be searched upon. I have noticed that some tags have synonyms which I want to add to the field, but in some cases the synonym already exists, in other cases not. For example after I have updated the tags, I can end up with the following (the tags are separated by spaces only):-

1. pool swimming pool ocean sea water
2. swim ocean sea water water swim
3. swimming pool swim swimming pool swim

Is there a way to eliminate duplicate text from the same field so I end up with this?

1. pool swimming ocean sea water swim
2. ocean sea water swim
3. pool swim swimming

Comment: Save yourself a nightmare. Redesign the database and write a script which goes through the existing records and recreates them in the new database design. Remember the quote: "Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live."

Answer (score 2):

The model you describe (all tags into a single cell, separated by spaces) is not normalized so you can't expect to find a simple, performant and reliable way to do stuff with it from the database server (beyond reading the column). The way it's now, PHP is your only chance to do the cleanup you are planning to do, and you'll have to retrieve every row.

Is it too late to make a little change in the database design? If you store each tag into a separate row in a `tag` table you'd be able to do lots of stuff from plain SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider keeping one entry per tag instead of all tags as a string, so that you could do a `select distinct` among other things.

Comment: Yes this is a good idea, unfortunately I did not design the database or script and do not have the time to go through it to making the necessary changes. There are also thousands of entries in there already.

Comment: The easiest way I see is using a script to make the changes. Something like `unique(split(tags))`. That's also how I'd convert your database. You can also try `select tags from splitstring(',', [list])`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version,you generate a large enough number of rows so you can CROSS JOIN progressively for each word then just GROUP_CONCAT  will once again concatenate the separate words with the added DISTINCT parameter.

A primary or unqiue key to group by would be better in case of identical rows.

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.col, ' ', x.cifre), ' ', -1)) AS words
FROM t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 + a.i + b.i * 10  cifre, b.i + a.i * 10  sute
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b
) x
ON (LENGTH(t.col) +1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.col, ' ', ''))) >= x.cifre
GROUP BY col
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1beb8/4)

Comment: I found your answer and fiddle example very useful +1 but I can't manage to update T table using your variant of query. Could you expand a little your script to update a column ?

Comment: @Serge Assuming a primary key,since in the real world this is very common http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cbca1/1

Comment: I would add +100 for your solution ! Very impressive !

Comment: I try to use the script for a field with about 500 words to exclude duplicates but it cut at a level of 115 words approx at the same place. I've added few more lines up to UNION SELECT 53 - but result is the same as with UNION SELECT 9. Could you hint what parameters I should play with to process all 500 words ?

Comment: @Serge Try running `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;` before your query.It will allow GROUP_CONCAT to hold a much larger value.If not recreate the issue on sqlfiddle.

Comment: YES, it has solved the issue ! Great thx once again for the perfect solution.

Comment: I met a necessity to call this procedure for a specific ID in table, not for the whole table...is it possible ?

Comment: @Serge Yes,add a WHERE id = someId  after `FROM t ` part

Comment: I guess that first :) but the problem is it does not work

Comment: as your previous SQLfiddle does not open - I recreate the one at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba6fad1/8 - but anyway SqlFiddle itself says something bad about DDL and DML statements. Please, have a look.

Comment: @http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22d1f6/1 Careful with the `tmp_table_size` variable,apparently there is a bug in mysql so we have to set it manually or DISITNCT wont work. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84320

Answer (score 0):

### If it's a real option,

**Change your database design.** I don't know about your time constraints so it may really not be an option, but consider which of these two paths you'd rather go down:

- A couple of hours *now* redesigning the database, then writing, debugging and verifying a script that'll take all the values from the existing layout and put them in the new one.
- Hours and hours later coming up with obscure queries for otherwise simple tasks that would take ten minutes to write a query for if the database was designed the way a relational database should be.

### If it's really not an option though...

```
Let Sentence = the string of words.
Split Sentence up on every space and build an array out of it*. Store this as Words.
Let UniqueWords = an array of words with no duplicates.
For each Word in Words:
     If the Word is not in UniqueWords, put it in.
```

*[a la PHP explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

You could also process it as a raw string (stopping to check at spaces or EOL), which may be faster, but if speed is important, your current database design should be far more concerning than this loop.

EDIT: I didn't see that you wanted it in a SQL query. I'm not sure it'd be possible using a query; perhaps a stored procedure will do. I don't know how to use those though.

Comment: Yes, to be honest I was very suprised to see the design of the database. I think I will go the php route, although the database wouldn't take long to redesign, I think it could take weeks to pick through someone elses poorly commented code to change the search and tagging system.

Answer (score 0):

+1 redesign, but if redesign is not an option now...

How many distinct tags are there? You might be able to do this using CASE and substring functions.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you're best to handle this with PHP

```
$uniqueTags = array_unique(explode(' ', $tagsFromDbColumn));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE word VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE i,wordcount INT(10) DEFAULT 1;
SET word = 'pool swimming pool ocean sea water';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dupliword;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dupliword(wordname VARCHAR(100));
SET wordcount = LENGTH(word) - LENGTH(REPLACE(word,' ',''))+1;
WHILE i <= wordcount DO
INSERT  INTO dupliword(wordname)
VALUES(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(word,' ',i),' ',-1));
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
SELECT  REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wordname),',',' ') FROM dupliword;
```