# Removing duplicate string in the same field

Tags: mysql

I happen to have some "bad" data in my DB, like this:

```
ID | name        |
 1 | Apple Apple | 
 2 | Banana      |
 3 | Orange      |
```

I inherited some names that are repeated like "Apple Apple".

How can I remove the duplicate "Apple" directly in MySQL, not using PHP or other server-side scripts.

the desired result should be just "Apple"

Comment: Can you have legitimate data in the name field that contains space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate words from field in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996831/remove-duplicate-words-from-field-in-mysql)

Comment: Remove what? Remove the row? Remove the second word? What if there is more than one word? What if there are two words that differ? Can there be three repeated words? Four? _Define your requirements._ Then show your attempts at satisfying them.

Comment: did u guys read the title?

Comment: Yes, we did. Did you read our questions?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table_name SET name='Apple' WHERE ID=1;

Comment: I was sooo thinking about adding this answer myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string and compare them.
Following script is written in MSSQL but you can understand the idea.

```
declare @z varchar(100);
set @z = 'Apple Apple'
--First Part, Second part
Select SUBSTRING(@z, 0, ((LEN(@z)+1)/2) + 1), SUBSTRING(@z, ((LEN(@z)+1)/2) + 1, LEN(@z))
```

your query should look like

```
Update Table_Name set 
Column_Name = Case
            When (firstPart = SecondPart)
            Then FirstPart
            Else Column_Name
            End

Update Table_Name 
set Column_Name = Case 
                when (SUBSTRING(@z, ((LEN(@z)+1)/2) + 1, LEN(@z)) = SUBSTRING(@z, 0, ((LEN(@z)+1)/2) + 1)) 
                Then SUBSTRING(@z, ((LEN(@z)+1)/2) + 1, LEN(@z))
                Else Column_Name
                End
```