# mySQL: Find repetitions of a string within a VARCHAR field?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like this

```
TITLE          |   DESCRIPTION
------------------------------------------------
test1          |   value blah blah value
test2          |   value test
test3          |   test test test
test4          |   value test value test
```

how to select only the rows that contain consequent redundant strings ("blah blah", but not "blah bleh blah")?

the desired output should be only

```
TITLE          |   DESCRIPTION
------------------------------------------------
test1          |   value blah blah value
test3          |   test test test
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Why does `value test value test` not have consecutive (I think that is the word you wanted to use) redundant strings?

Answer (score 1):

You could create for this problem (and many other problems) a helper table (just once), which contains natural numbers. It can be used for many purposes:

```
create table seq (num int);
insert into seq values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8);
insert into seq select num+8  from seq;
insert into seq select num+16 from seq;
insert into seq select num+32 from seq;
insert into seq select num+64 from seq;
/* continue doubling the number of records until you feel you have enough */
```

Then you can join that table in your query, where each number is used as a sequence number of a word in a phrase. That way you can extract each word and compare it with the next:

```
select     title, description
from       phrases
where      description not in (
        select     description
        from       phrases p
        inner join seq 
                on seq.num <= length(p.description)
                            - length(replace(p.description,' ',''))
               and substring_index(substring_index(
                                   description, ' ', num), ' ', -1)
                   = substring_index(substring_index(
                                   description, ' ', num+1), ' ', -1)
        )
```

The output for the sample data is:

```
| title |           description |
|-------|-----------------------|
| test2 |            value test |
| test4 | value test value test |
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1c96/6)

Comment: wow thank you. one thing: i don't understand "until you feel you have enough" what do you mean for "enough" given i have about 15K rows in my table. thanks!

Comment: also, what would be the way to remove the redundancy instead of just selecting? i can do it pretty easily in PHP... but is it possible in mysql?

Comment: "Enough" in this case means you need to know what are the longest descriptions you will have in terms of word-count. If you have descriptions that could have 1000 words, then you need to make sure the numbers 1..1000 are in the `seq` table. To remove the redundancy is possible, but complex:  I would do that in PHP. If you need a pure MySql solution, I would suggest to ask a new question about that. Previous similar questions exist (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996831/remove-duplicate-words-from-field-in-mysql)), but do not seem to give the perfect solution.